# How to build and deploy BPF BCC C++ apps?

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, bcc-bpf

There's plenty of docs for python developers, but as a C++ developer very new to BCC/BPF i'm finding it very difficult to determine where to start in building and deploying BCC-based C++ apps.

Where do i start? I've looked at the examples but they don't give any idea on how to package up a BCC C++ app for deployment on a wide range of Linux distributions.

How do i go about doing this? what issues/concerns are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been developing a BPF tool in C++ (https://github.com/toru/h2olog), but I think there are few documents about it. I've learned C++ binding from [examples/cpp](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/tree/master/examples/cpp/*.cc) and [BPF.h](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/src/cc/api/BPF.h).

However, I recommend using Python 3 binding for BCC unless you have performance issues on the BPF tools you'll develop. This is because C++ binding is hard to lean (as you are asking), and hard to use metaprogramming (thus we're using code generation).

Comment: Thanks, but i need C++. But all tthat is requires to deploy it is tthat tthe target system has BCC installed?

Comment: What if i want to distribute pre-compiled binaries to end users?

Comment: The target system must have BCC installed. I've tried to link BCC to our tool statically, but I could not have succeeded it, so I have no idea for the static linking of BCC.

Comment: 私の友人、どうもありがとう。I appreciate it.

Comment: cpp examples link was not working for me, try this instead:
https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/examples/cpp